# Why can't I use the pin operator in an Elixir closure function head?

Tags: elixir

Normally in Elixir I can use the pin operator to specify the value bound to an existing name ie:

```
a = 1
{^a, b} = {1,2}
# b is now 2
```

works as expected.

However I don't seem to be able to pin values like this in a closure function head, ie:

```
a = 1
f = fn
  ^a -> true
  _ -> false
end
```

results in a compile failure:
`** (CompileError) iex:2: unbound variable ^a`

Is there a reason for this, and a correct way to achieve the same result?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing conceptually wrong with your code. It doesn't work because it is a limitation in current Elixir version that will be addressed on Elixir v1.2.

You can achieve the same result with:

```
a = 1
f = fn
  new_a when a === new_a -> true
  _ -> false
end
```

Comment: Straight from the source of truth!  :)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to the above problem seems to be to use a case statement inside the closure, though it feel unnecessarily convoluted.

```
a = 1

f = fn n ->
  case n do
    ^a -> true
    _ -> false
  end
end

f.(1)
# true
f.(2)
# false
```

While this works, it highlights how odd it is that I cannot use the pin operator directly in the fn head.

Answer (score 0):

This comes straight from an answer that José posted to a different question:

> Elixir allows rebinding only in the same scope and all constructs, with the exception of case, cond and receive, introduce a new scope.

Hence you can't pin *a* because it's a new scope.

Comment: I must be having a slow morning, but could you elaborate on why the creation of a new scope stops the pinning of a, afterall, I'm explicitly not rebinding a, but rather dereferencing its value into the pattern when I pin aren't I, isn's this the same as when I dereference any other closed over binding?

Comment: The value of _a_ you're trying to pin doesn't exist.  It's a  new scope.  When you use case you do not get a new scope hence _a_ is defined.

Comment: I would be able to use the value of a from within the closure body though wouldn't I?